# SQL query for 2 tables using group by

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
restaurant(id,name);
rating(id,rating,restaurant);
```

What I'm doing is:

```
select 
    rt.name, avg(rg.rating) as rating
from
    restaurant rt,
    rating rg
where
    rg.restaurant = rt.id
group by rg.restaurant;
```

This is giving me a table with restaurant name and average rating for each restaurant. What I need is also the name of the tables for which there is no rating yet.

Comment: You're probably looking for a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Can you give me the query for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as Matt mentioned in the comment:

```
SELECT `rt`.`name`, AVG(`rg`.`rating`) AS `rating` 
FROM `restaurant` `rt`, `rating` `rg` 
LEFT JOIN `rg`.`restaurant` = `rt`.`id` GROUP BY `rg`.`restaurant`
```

Answer (score -2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d50c0/1)

```
SELECT
restaurant.Name, avg(rating.Rating)
From restaurant
LEFT JOIN rating on rating.restaurant = restaurant.ID
GROUP BY rating.restaurant
```

for no rating yet restaurant:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d50c0/8)

```
SELECT
restaurant.Name, avg(rating.Rating)
From restaurant
LEFT JOIN rating on rating.restaurant = restaurant.ID
GROUP BY rating.restaurant
HAVING     avg(rating.Rating) <=0
```